# Using property with and without self for @synthesis property=ivar

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter, getter

From what I understand I should always use self.property_name everywhere except in getter and setter when using property, but in case I declared @synthesis property_name=ivar does omit self.property equal using property_name alone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following your question complete, but if you are asking does using the following:

```
@synthesize property_name=ivar
```

mean that you could use both `self.property_name` or just `property_name` the answer is no.  If you wanted to use it without the `self` you would have to reference if via the `ivar`.

That is only true, of course, if you only declared the variable using `@property` and `@synthesize` and didn't also include it as an ivar in the `@interface` declaration

Comment: If I declare `@synthesis property_name=ivar` I can access via getter and setter by self.property name and ivar for direct access.
In case of `@synthesis property_name` I can access via getter and setter by self.property_name and property_name for direct access, correct ?